# How to select values from multi select dropdown in struts and save in database

Tags: struts-1, html-select

Hi i am using multi select drop-down in struts .Value i am displaying in drop-down from database .I need that user should be able to select multiple values from the drop down and then he can save to database .
Here is what i have tried so far.
This is my struts design

```
<TD>
                                <html:select property="bammenity1"  multiple="true" style=" width:150px"  >
                                    <html:optionsCollection  name="AmntyType"  value="amenityType" label="amenityType" />
                                </html:select> <a href="AddAmenity.jsp"><bean:message key="addamenity"/></a><br/>
                            </TD>

 try{

    bus.setBammenity1((String[]) addbustypeform.get("bammenity1"));

    }catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("Exception"+e.toString());
    }
```

Problem i am facing is that after selcting multiple value i am getting only one selected value
Please reply soon